# How to communicate with a client app on an idle/sleeping/locked Android device from server?

Tags: android, tcp, sleep, locked

I am trying to figure out how to send event actions to my client app from the server when the device has gone to sleep/idle/locked.

I know this is possible as I can see Whatsapp/Facebook/Viber calls waking the device immediately on incoming call and starting their dialer activity. This means they can communicate with the app. More than just sending a notification to be displayed.

Currently I have implemented it in what I believe is a kind of workaround way. I send a push notification from the server, which in turn is received on a `PushBroadCastReceiver` in the client app side. Then, this receiver starts my service which maintains a TCP connection with my server. At this point I can start communicating with my app through this service by sending messages/event actions to the TCP connection.

It works, but nevertheless I feel this way is quirky and they must be doing it in some better way. But I can't think of one. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Your current method is probably the most efficient way to do it. Alternatives require keeping another persistent network connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure if this is really the most efficient way because it seems too slow. The receiver performs 'context.startService()' and the service connects with the server on its 'onStartCommand()', but it seems 'startService()' still takes a few seconds sometimes (depending how long the device has been idle) until it starts the service. So what happens now is I have to wait in a sleep loop on the server side for the service to start on the device. Must be a better way...Anyone out there knows how FB/Whatsapp do it?

Comment: By efficient I meant power-friendly. Make sure you are using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver which will set up a wake lock so your service will not be interrupted.

Comment: GCM, XMPP, Sockets....

Comment: @BladeCoder - Are you familiar with Parse? I am actually using 'ParsePushBroadcastReceiver', extending it and overriding the onPushReceive() method I added the call: Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        context.startService(i);
I also at one time used a wake lock in the same onPushReceive() method, but I figured the push notification itself acquires a wake lock, so that's redundant. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: I was not aware of Parse and by looking at the source code I see that ParsePushBroadcastReceiver does not acquire any wake lock automatically. The system takes care of waking up the CPU during the execution of the BroadcastReceiver like you say, but if the BroadcastReceiver starts a Service you need to acquire a wake lock or the CPU can stop during the service execution. For more details, please read this: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/i6MzCp1NyzF

Comment: @BladeCoder - Thanks a lot for the help! I guess my mistake was assuming it acquired a wake lock because the Parse integration includes adding a wake lock permission in the manifest. I will check your link and report later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but perhaps an [AlarmManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you're looking for. Rather than pushing from the server to the client, you just have the client wake up and request info from the server at a regular interval. Here's a snippet of code that I have used to periodically send location information.

```
public class LocationRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "Location Request Receiver";

    public LocationRequestReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, LocationRequestService.class);
        }
        else {
            scheduleLocationRequestService(context);
        }
    }

    public static void scheduleLocationRequestService(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Scheduling Location Request Service");
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationRequestReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Constants.INITIAL_DELAY,
                Constants.PASSIVE_LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not exactly what I want because I need the initiative to come from the server. Note the examples I have mentioned: VoiP calls on FB/Whatsapp. you can easily experiment and make a call to a device which has been idle for long. The incoming call reaction is immediate. There must be some way they are doing it apart from my push notifications and your AlarmManager suggestion.

Any FB/Whatspp employees in the crowd?

Comment: Eventually I solved it by using Alarm Manager to send keep alives\heartbeats to the server every 1 minute. I hope it's not too battery consuming

Comment: I can't speak for iOS but Google suggests every 5 minutes as appropriate for conserving battery life. Only on my phone and I'm too lazy to find the documentation, but you may want to throttle back to that if your solution can wait an extra 4 minutes

Comment: Thanks! I may very well give it a shot.